# How to automate the process of building several models in R

Tags: string, r, formula, paste, linear-regression

I have been trying to automate the process of building several models using a for loop, but I am getting an error each time. I need to build about 50 or more models, say like the following,

linearModel.1 = lm(y ~ ., data = train.1)
...

linearModel.50 = lm(y~ ., data = train.50)

Instead of doing it this way (write down each line for each model), I wanted to use for loop and paste0 function like this

```
for (i in 1:50){
paste0("linearModel.",i) = lm(y~ ., data = paste0("train.",i))
}
```

But each time I getting the following error:

Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  '.' in formula and no 'data' argument

Can anybody help me set it up ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simply `paste0` use `eval(parse(text = paste0("linearmodel.",i)))`and `eval(parse(text = paste0("train.",i)))`. For storing models I recommend to use list.

Comment: Thanks, but can you be little bit more specific. I am still getting error. Here is what I tried, for(i in 1:3){paste0("linearModel",i) = lm(reimbursement2009~., data = eval(parse(text = paste0("train",i))))} and the error is                 "Error in paste0("linearModel", i) = lm(y ~ ., data = eval(parse(text = paste0("train",  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object"

Comment: You have to change this paste0 for eval(parse(...)) in both places. Check my post